# How to stylize a combo box?

Tags: javascript, combobox

How can be styled a combo box?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do much with regular CSS. Try with jQuery plugins, like [this one](http://jquery.sanchezsalvador.com/page/jquerycombobox.aspx) or read more about [enhancing dropdowns](http://www.reynoldsftw.com/2009/03/11-jquery-plugins-to-enhance-html-dropdowns/).

Answer (score 1):

You can't do much, without replacing it with something that emulates the functionality without truly being a "select element".

If you're interested in that though, here's a couple good articles about it:

[`<select>` Something New, Part 1](http://v2.easy-designs.net/articles/replaceSelect/)

[`<select>` Something New, Part 2](http://v2.easy-designs.net/articles/replaceSelect2/)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the enitre look of a select box ( making custom image as arrow button etc ) you can use a div and can code in JavaScript to behave like a combo box.

Check [this](http://www.dotnetgoodies.com/article/Javascript/63/How_to_create_a_ComboBox_using_JavaScript.aspx) for a nice one in javascript